# How to read a dataset member with a dollar character in its name with ZOAU Python API?

Tags: python, zos, zoau

From [USS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=zos-unix-system-services), I can read a dataset member with a dollar character in its name with:

```
 dtail -n +1 'ZXP.CONTEST.Q42021.SOURCE(PART$G)'
```

From Python 3, I can read a dataset member without dollar characters with:

```
from zoautil_py import datasets
dsname = 'ZXP.CONTEST.Q42021.SOURCE'
datasets.read(dsname + '(ASM@419)')
```

But when I try:

```
from zoautil_py import datasets
dsname = 'ZXP.CONTEST.Q42021.SOURCE'
datasets.read(dsname + '(PART$G)')
```

I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lpp/IBM/zoautil/lib/zoautil_py/datasets.py", line 64, in read
    raise ZOAUException(response.stderr_response)
zoautil_py.exceptions.ZOAUException: BGYSC1304E Unable to open dataset ZXP.CONTEST.Q42021.SOURCE(PART) for read.
```

So my question is: How to read a dataset member with a dollar character in the member name with [ZOAU Python API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/z-modernization-stack/2022.4?topic=utilities-python-api-reference)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the $ sign

```
>>> from zoautil_py import datasets
>>> datasets.read('USER.TEST.PDS(PART\$G)')
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor[...]'
```

Comment: I was thinking that I already tried this. But in fact, it works. Thank you.